# JavaFX でボタンを押したら背景色が変わるコードを作成したい

Tags: java, javafx

ボタンを押したら背景色が変わり、なおかつその色が選ばれました。という JavaFX を書いています。

しかし、画像の赤線の通り、以下のエラーがそれぞれ出ています。

setOnActionの部分:

```
型 ButtonBase のメソッド setOnAction(EventHandler<ActionEvent>) は引数 (Renshu2.SampleEventHandler) に適用できません
```

ActionEvent の部分:

```
制約の不一致: 型 ActionEvent は、型 EventHandler<T> の制約付きパラメーター <T extends Event> の代替として有効ではありません
```

これらのエラーを解決したいのですが、多分このコードだと、ボタンの背景色が変わるだけだと思うんですが、全体の背景色を変える方法を教えてください。実装の仕方が分かりません。

**ソースコード:**

```java
package renshu1;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Renshu2 extends Application {
    private Label lb1,lb2;
    private Button bt1,bt2,bt3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage stage)throws Exception
    {
        lb1 = new Label("背景色を選んでください。");
        lb2 = new Label("");
        bt1 = new Button("Cyan");
        bt2 = new Button("Yellow");
        bt3 = new Button("Pink");
        
        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
        HBox hb = new HBox();
        
        hb.getChildren().add(bt1);
        hb.getChildren().add(bt2);
        hb.getChildren().add(bt3);
        hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        
        bp.setTop(lb1);
        bp.setBottom(lb2);
        bp.setCenter(hb);
        
        //イベントハンドラの登録
        bt1.setOnAction(new SampleEventHandler());
        bt2.setOnAction(new SampleEventHandler());
        bt3.setOnAction(new SampleEventHandler());
        
        
        Scene sc = new Scene(bp,300,200);
        
        stage.setScene(sc);
        
        stage.setTitle("背景色の変化");
        stage.show();
    }
    
    class SampleEventHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>, 
    {
        public void handle(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Button tmp = (Button) e.getSource();
            lb2.setText(tmp.getText() + "が選ばれました。");
            if(tmp == bt1)
            bt1.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.CYAN,null,null)));
            
            else if(tmp == bt2)
            bt2.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.YELLOW,null,null)));
            else if(tmp == bt3)
            bt3.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.PINK,null,null)));
                
            }
            
        }
    
        
        
        
        // TODO 自動生成されたメソッド・スタブ

    }
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    at renshu1.Renshu2.main(Renshu2.java:22)
    ... 11 more
Exception running application renshu1.Renshu2
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

記載にあったような実行時エラーのまえに、変なカンマがあってコンパイルできませんでした。

```java
    class SampleEventHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>, 
    {
```

また、JavaFXのアプリケーションなのに、awtのActionEventをインポートしているのもなんなのかと。

```java
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
```

> 全体の背景色を変える方法を教えてください。実装の仕方が分かりません。

こんな感じで。

スタイルについては、 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html をどうぞ。

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Renshu2 extends Application {
  private Label lb1, lb2;
  private Button bt1, bt2, bt3;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    lb1 = new Label("背景色を選んでください。");
    lb2 = new Label("");
    bt1 = new Button("Cyan");
    bt2 = new Button("Yellow");
    bt3 = new Button("Pink");

    final HBox hb = new HBox(bt1, bt2, bt3);
    hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    final BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
    bp.setTop(lb1);
    bp.setBottom(lb2);
    bp.setCenter(hb);

    //イベントハンドラの登録
    final SampleEventHandler ev = new SampleEventHandler();
    bt1.setOnAction(ev);
    bt2.setOnAction(ev);
    bt3.setOnAction(ev);

    Scene sc = new Scene(bp, 300, 200);

    stage.setScene(sc);

    stage.setTitle("背景色の変化");
    stage.show();
  }

  class SampleEventHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
      final Button button = (Button) e.getSource();
      button.getParent().setStyle(String.format("-fx-background-color: %s;", button.getText()));
      lb2.setText(button.getText() + "が選ばれました。");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: できました。ありがとうございました。